# Must I have publications in an area in order to list it as an academic interest on my personal website?

Tags: publications

What is the etiquette on listing your academic interests on a personal or academic webpage?

For example, if I list "optimization" as an interest on my webpage, but don't yet have any publications in mathematical optimization, and am not an expert in the field (but perhaps do have personal projects and coursework) will this be looked down upon? I don't want to accidentally give the impression that I am an expert by listing it as an interest.

I am a graduate student getting started in a new field.

Comment: The few people who will look at your website will not jump to conclusions about your actual expertise.

Comment: The answers here are helpful but there is one small point to be made which may help you. It is not a question of following *rules* here. If anyone looks at your site it will be a human being seeing what sort of human being you are. So - you, yourself - spend some time looking at personal websites similar to yours. *What impression does a site give you?* You will find yourself distinguishing sane from insane, expert from amateur, “genuine interest” from “let me add this keyword”. It’s like reading a dating site profile. Then look at your own site with the same eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt anyone would look down on you for making a statement of interest. I assume you aren't intending to say anything that suggests expertise. Most mathematicians have interest in one (or a few) special areas. It is fine to say that. Your CV will make it clear where your expertise lies.

Answer (score 0):

Having publications in a particular field **is not necessary** to be able to write that area on your interests. This is especially applicable when you are just starting to work in a specific field, which is exactly your situation. Your interest implies that you are dedicating time and effort to exploring that topic and aspire to make contributions to the field.
It's worth noting that while many individuals have publications within their area of expertise, this is often because they have worked for long time on that area and they are not beginners.